# What does Java's Enum<?> mean and why isn't it compatible with Enum?

Tags: java, enums, type-erasure

I'm refactoring someone else's code and They use the type `Enum<?>` in several places.  It would be a huge pain to get rid of it, and it seems like it should be compatible with a non-generic Java Enum type declaration since they both having nothing to say about the type parameter to the generic type.

I've created this code snippet to demonstrate the problem that has the compile errors noted in the comments:

```
enum Shapes {   
  SQUARE,
  CIRCLE 
};

enum Colors {
    RED,
    BLUE,
    GREEN
  };
public void testEnumConversions() throws Exception {
  List<Enum<?>> colors = ImmutableList.<Enum<?>>of(Colors.RED, Colors.GREEN, Shapes.SQUARE);
  List<Enum> colors2 = 
      ImmutableList.<Enum<?>>of(Colors.RED, Colors.GREEN); // incompatible types
  List<Enum> colors3 = 
      (List<Enum>)ImmutableList.<Enum<?>>of(Colors.RED, Colors.GREEN); // inconvertible types
  List<Enum> colors4 = ImmutableList.<Enum>of(Colors.RED, Colors.GREEN, Shapes.SQUARE);
  List<Enum<?>> colors5 = ImmutableList.of(Colors.RED, Colors.GREEN, Shapes.SQUARE);
  List<Enum> colors6 = 
      ImmutableList.of(Colors.RED, Colors.GREEN, Shapes.SQUARE); // incompatible types;

}
```

Why isn't `List<Enum<?>>` compatible with `List<Enum>`?  They seem identical to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **everything** doesn't say the same as **something**.

Same with `Comparable`. `Comparable` is `Comparable<Object>`, so it must be comparable to everything. `Comparable<?>` says "there is something I can compare it with, but I don't know what.

Same here: `Enum` is "Enumeration of everything". Whereas `Enum<?>` is "Enumeration of something that I do not know".

This brings us to the difference of `List<Enum>` to `List<Enum<?>>`. The first can contain or take enums of arbitrary type. For the latter, all elements must agree.

I strongly advise against either. Generics are a powerful tool to avoid programming errors. They make your life easier. So understand them, and use them to your advantage. So here, you should be using `List<Shapes>` and `List<Colors>`.

Comment: How would you explain the fact that the colors5 declaration/initialiation compiles without warnings or errors?  It contains both shapes and colors.

Comment: Magic type inference in `ImmutableList.of` probably decided you mean a list of Type `List<? extends Enum<? extends Enum>>` or something like this. I.e. it discovered a common supertype of both.

Comment: I think I see what you mean about List<? extends<Enum<? extends Enum>>>, but wouldn't that be 100% compatible with a list containing any kind of enumeration, which is what a List<Enum> is?  If so, why the compile errors?

Comment: Well, technically, `Enum` is a `Enum<Object>`, ignoring the fact that `Object` does _not_ extend `Enum`. This is okay for the bytecode (since the code is compiled with type erasure); but it doesn't make the types equal for the typechecking compiler.

Comment: BTW the contrived example didn't make clear the necessity of this.  I'm working on a tool that works on metadata to create combinations of enumerated values based on input from clients, so the enumeration types are necessarily unknowable prior to runtime.

Comment: Don't use `Enum` for that. Enums are just a tool to make less programming errors by producing compile time errors for invalid values, but when the values aren't known at compile time anyway, use for example integers or strings.

Comment: The values are meaningful to the clients, to force them to use integers with this tool and maintain the mapping between meaningful name used internally and meaningless number used when using this tool wouldn't make sense.  In some configurations The enum values are passed by name on the command line, for example.  Since the enum type name and value name are known, reflection is used to retrieve the enum values and pass them to the clients.  The command line would become inscrutable if integers were used.  Enums are the right level of specificity.